# Eclipse на MAC OS X видит разные JAVA

Tags: eclipse, android, java, jvm

Добрый день, всем.

Установил последнюю сборку JDK (8u31) на 64-разрядный.
Скачал Eclipse на 64-разрядный.
При попытке установки Eclipse выдает ошибку:
`Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version: 1.7 or greater required.`

В терминале java -version

`java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-466.1-11M4716)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-466.1, mixed mode)`

В настройках системы -> JAVA. Видит 1.8 правильно:

[image]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где что изменить, чтобы видел правильную JAVA_HOME.

P.S. Смотрел на stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598465/eclipse-in-os-x-uses-different-version-of-java-than-cli/), не нашел ответа. (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решился вопрос, если кому интересно будет. ) Все намного легче.
[Здесь написано](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/792447/).